# Corda node shutdown along with spring boot client

Tags: corda

*I have a node which is running on my machine along with a spring boot client. Client connects to node's rpc port, every thing works well but when i close my client the node crashes and i have to restart it. Why its happening is it a bug or i am doing some thing wrong. I have also deployed them on cloud and same problem happens.*

```
 Corda Open Source 4.0 (503a2ff) May 16 11:37:43 broker java[16853]: Logs can be found in : /opt/corda/logs May 16 11:37:58 broker java[16853]: Advertised P2P messaging addresses : 35.228.97.4:10011 May 16 11:37:58 broker java[16853]: RPC connection address : 10.166.0.2:10012 May 16 11:37:58 broker java[16853]: RPC admin connection address : 10.166.0.2:10050 May 16 11:38:01 broker java[16853]: Loaded 2 CorDapp(s) : Contract CorDapp: Template CorDapp version 1 by vendor Corda Ope May 16 11:38:01 broker java[16853]: Node for "Broker" started up and registered in 19.86 sec May 16 11:38:01 broker java[16853]: SSH server listening on port : 2222 May 16 12:10:03 broker java[16853]: Shutting down ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you create your `CordaRPCOps` class.

If it is a bean, then it will call `CordaRPCOps.shutdown` when the client is shutdown. This is due to Spring triggering any method named `shutdown` on any beans by default. Therefore by not creating it as a bean, for example having a wrapper class around `CordaRPCOps` that is created as a bean instead will resolve this issue.

Or you can tell spring to not trigger the shutdown method by defining your bean like:

```java
@Bean(destroyMethod = "")
public CordaRPCOps proxy() {}
```

Comment: Don't you think this should be handled by corda, anyone with wrong implementation can shut down the node.

Comment: We had this discussion internally, and for now, we have decided that it is not our fault that spring is calling this function. We are keeping are public api stable and therefore cannot change this. This might change in the future, but not at the moment. Although people can shutdown their node, as long as they have tested there app locally at all, they should pick up on this. Unfortunately, it is pretty annoying :/